Meaning of the name Kaiba
we have created a recognition for proactivity in my company and decided to let the employees name it. The most voted name was “Kaiba”. According to the person who proposed it, Kaiba is the name of a dragon and it is associated to positive values of courage and strength. But before oficially naming the prize, we want to make sure that that is the real meaning and there are no inconvenient associations to the word in its original Japanese. Thank you

Presumably this?

The only word I think of when I see that spelling is 海馬, which means the hippocampus (in the brain). Nothing negative but nothing positive either.

Thank you. Is it only the hippocampus in the brain and not the sea-horse, which is the Greek origin of the word hippocampus? This would explain the association to a dragon, as a sea monster.

Kaiba is written as 海馬 in kanji, where the character 海 means "sea" and 馬 means "horse". 海馬 is one of the Japanese names for seahorse, which is better known in Japan as タツノオトシゴ (tatsu-no-otoshigo; literally "dragon's offspring"). Therefore, although its literal meaning ("sea-horse") has nothing to do with a dragon, it does refer to a certain fish species associated by the Japanese with a child dragon. Still, it's the name of a fish, and it sounds a little far-fetched to me to say kaiba is the name of a dragon.
Culturally, seahorses was used as medicine. It was also customary to use dried seahorses as charms for safe childbirth. While they are often regarded as mystical creatures, I doubt they symbolize courage and strength like true dragons do.
The hippocampus of the brain is named after this species. Both the Latinate hippocampus and the Japanese 海馬 can refer to either the fish or the brain structure.
